# Error ORA-03134: Connections to this server version are no longer supported

Tags: asp.net, oracle

En una aplicación web utilizo 2 conexiones a 2 servidores distintos de Oracle 10g, utilizo Visual Studio 2015 Professional, y he instalado en el ordenador de desarrollo las librerías de Oracle ODAC 12, tengo referenciado en la aplicación dicha librería `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`.

El caso es que la conexión a uno de los servidores funciona correctamente y cuando ha de abrir la conexión a otro me reportar el error:

```
 ORA-03134: Connections to this server version are no longer supported
```

¿Me pueden dar alguna pista de por dónde va el problema? Aparentemente ambos servidores ORACLE tienen la misma configuración.

Comment: Estas seguro de que ambos servidores corren la misma versión de Oracle? Ese error tiene pinta de ser por incompatibilidad entre la versión del conector y la del Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente he realizado un dblink al servidor que no me dá problemas y en el he implementado las vistas materializadas que necesitba. todo resuelto.

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error dice que estás usando diferentes versiones de Oracle. Referencia [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28278/e2100.htm#sthref1232)

```
ORA-03134: Connections to this server version are no longer supported.
Cause: An attempt was made to connect to an Oracle server of older version.
Action: Please refer to documentation for more details.
```

Para comprobar la versión del motor de la base de datos ejecuta la query:

```
select * from v$version;
```

Ten en cuenta la versión del cliente que estás usando. Si es antigua te tocará hacer un upgrade de la aplicación o el driver.